# STM32F030P6 MCU returning high even when no voltage is measured on the pin

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, stm32cubeide

I am trying to make a custom PCB based on stm32f030p6 MCU. one of the requirements is to read a pin's value (digitally i.e. high or low).
for this purpose I am using stm32CubeIDE, and to read the pin's value, its first initialised as below:

```
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

and the value is recorded like this:

```
int cc = 0;


while (1)
  {
    cc = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA,6);
    if(cc)
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    else
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
```

above is the complete piece of simple code i wrote to test if the pin reads correctly by examining the state of pin 4 to see if its high meaning that the MCU has recorded pin 6 as high or low and pin 4 is initalised as follows:

```
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

and even when there is no voltage, it still returns the pins status as 1 (HIGH).

I did this again after enabling the internal pull down ressitor:

```
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

still to no avail.

I made sure this is not a hardware problem by basically converting the pin to ana anlog input and doing a simple if statement:

```
if( the_measured_voltage_on_pin < 0.3V){
do sth;
}
```

and it worked fine. I confirmed this by applying a 2.5V voltage to the pin and it worked fine, so its more likely than not that its a pure software problem, but i am getting no where in figuring out where this issue is arising from.

Any help or hints would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time,
Ali

Comment: you let the pin float by NOPULL option, if you are not using an external pull down resistor. If you aren't, just use the internal pull-down resistor to ensure pin  reads low when there is not a high signal connected.

Comment: How and where do you set up pin 4? How do you know that the function always returns 1, do you know this by watching the variable in a debugger or by watching pin 4?

Comment: @Lundin    Thank you for your comment, I added the bit on how I initalise pin 4. And I am basically seeing pin4 to know if the MCU has read high or low on pin 6.

Comment: How does the ST bloatware handle multiple calls to `HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);`? Is the function writing to different hardware registers? Doesn't seem like you are doing yourself any favours using their confusing API for something as mundane and trivial as GPIO.

Comment: @Lundin though I am not a fan of their HAL library, there is not a problem in that part.

Comment: does the fact that you're writing GPIO_PIN_SET to to pin 4 whether (cc) or (not cc) have anything to do with it?

Comment: @muyustan Looking at the `HAL_GPIO_Init` bloatware source, I'm not so convinced. That function sets up _all_ pins on the port. It can only handle one mode per port. If that same restriction is present in the hardware, I don't know, but it seems mighty strange that you aren't able to set pull-down on individual pins.

Comment: @Neil_UK Oh damn, you are right! That's silly and nobody spotted it. Facepalm time... You should post that as the answer to the question, I think.

Comment: @Lundin http://www.disca.upv.es/aperles/arm_cortex_m3/llibre/st/STM32F439xx_User_Manual/stm32f4xx__hal__gpio_8c_source.html#l00187   if you examine IO direction mode configuration for example, it is not overwriting anything, just adding to the registers. So previous information is not lost.

Comment: @Neil_UK bruh I was going crazy over this u know!!! i don't know how i sometimes go on into full on stupid mode! damn so dissapointed :)  thank you for your sharp eyes bud

Comment: @muyustan The key is `for(position = 0U; position < GPIO_NUMBER; position++)` and then inside the loop `if((GPIO_Init->Mode == ... GPIOx->PUPDR =  ...`. It appears to set all pins to the same mode. How does that make any sense? And all of this is truly the purest form of bloatware, programs don't get much uglier than this.

Comment: @Lundin thank you for your input

Comment: @muyustan thank you for your input

Comment: Regardless, I'd strongly advise you to drop the horrible ST library and just write to the GPIO registers directly. It ain't rocket science. Write to data direction register, pull register, done. A few lines of C code.

Comment: @Lundin I look few more times but still, it is not setting all pins, only the ones you inputted it with  `GPIO_InitStruct.Pin`. Nevertheless, I totally agree with your last comment.

Comment: @muyustan But it still iterates over all pins. And you have to do it over and over again, calling this function 32 times or so if you need individual pin configurations. Worse yet, it also does write to the actual hardware registers each time, even if it preserves the pin settings there. It's perfectly clear that the person who wrote the source & API of `HAL_GPIO_Init` was a complete amateur.

Comment: @Lundin ok, I thought we were arguing on usage of `HAL_GPIO_Init` might be the root cause of the problem of OP. If not, and we are arguing on efficiency of `HAL_GPIO_Init` then, well, nothing to say, it is bad.

Comment: @AliKavoosi I do it all the time, copy-paste then forget to edit. It's one of the disadvantages of having long_readable_descriptive names, typing from scratch is such a bore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (1)
  {
    cc = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA,6);
    if(cc)
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    else
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
```

This bit of code is writing GPIO_PIN_SET to pin 4, whether cc, pin 6, is true or not. So pin 4 will always be high.

Comment: That is a non-working example. GPIO_ReadPin takes in a bitmask, not pin number, so that returns two GPIO pins 1 and 2, as 6 is a mask for bits 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

The ReadPin takes in a bit mask for data, not the pin number, so it is now returning you bitmask with two pins.

Simply use the bitmask provided by the macro GPIO_PIN_6 in place of the number 6.